# image not able to showing using img tag inhtml

Tags: html, image

I facing the issue i.e, i want to show image in my html page so i used img tag in that i give img src but i am not able show the image.

this is the my image path in my system
C:\Users\sp\Desktop\UI developement_HTML_Daily practice samples\image.png

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Using Image in Webpage</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>Simple Image Insert</p>
<img src="image.png" alt="Test Image" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you have to add UI developement_HTML_Daily practice samples before the image like so <img src="UI developement_HTML_Daily practice samples/image.png" alt="Test Image">  although that's a big folder name, I would change it to images or something shorter before you upload it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to deploy this site, you should deploy the image as well.

I suggest (as kind of a best practice approach) you create a folder `images` or `pics` in the same directory as your index.html file. Copy your picture into this folder and then use the link:

```
<img src="images/image.png" alt="Test Image">
```

That way you can easily deploy your project folder in the future and will have all files properly linked.